# /media/administrator directory showing 2 folders of the same external usb drive

Tags: mount, external-hdd

While I was copying a file from my external HDD to my internal my Ubuntu crashed. This caused a problem, because now i have 2 folders in my `/media/administrator` folder, one is named after my external HDD and the other is also named after my external HDD except it has the number 1 in the end (I will post screenshots). Whenever I try to access the original folder it says access denied and if I go to properties it shows I have 31GB of storage which is wrong, but when I try to access the duplicate I can do it just fine, and when i go to properties it shows 1TB like it should. My question is how can I make it back to normal, and by that i mean having only one folder in `/media/administrator` when I connect my external hard drive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. To be sure, unmount your external HDD and check the folders in `/media/administrator` again. Now, there should be only one (empty) folder. Remove the folder with `sudo` rights:

```
sudo rmdir /media/administrator/HDD1
```

---

*Explanation*

Your system usually creates and removes the folders automatically, if you plugging an external device. The problem was, your Ubuntu crashed. Therefore the system can't remove the folder and the next created folder becomes a suffix, the number `1`.

Comment: It worked thank you very much, also thank you for managing to organize my post a lot better :DDDD

Comment: @holyslayerpt As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)